Issue with setting the font size of the Telerik <ol> list
Actually the <ol> tag font-size is getting as 1 after received the output even the <li><font>listItem01</font></li> font size is bigger (1,, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0r 7), so here using RadEdior from Telerik, actually Telerik have 1 to 7 font sizes so as per the Telerik solution I tried to set the font-size for <ol> with the first  item font-size of that particular <ol>.
So this is what I tried
function OnClientCommandExecuting(sender, args) {
    let commandName = args.get_commandName();
    if (commandName === "InsertOrderedList") {
        let doc = sender.get_document();

        setTimeout(function () {
            let olElements = doc.getElementsByTagName("ol");

            if (olElements.length > 0) {
                let getLastOrderList = olElements[olElements.length - 1];
                let firstListOfOrderList = getLastOrderList.getElementsByTagName("li")[0];

                if (firstListOfOrderList) {
                    let fontElements = firstListOfOrderList.getElementsByTagName("font");
                    let firstLiFontSize = 'small'; 

                    if (fontElements.length > 0) {
                        let firstFontTag = fontElements[0];
                        let fontSize = firstFontTag.getAttribute("size");

                        if (fontSize) {
                            fontSize = parseInt(fontSize, 10);
                            switch (fontSize) {
                                case 1: firstLiFontSize = 'x-small'; break;
                                case 2: firstLiFontSize = 'small'; break;
                                case 3: firstLiFontSize = 'medium'; break;
                                case 4: firstLiFontSize = 'large'; break;
                                case 5: firstLiFontSize = 'x-large'; break;
                                case 6: firstLiFontSize = 'xx-large'; break;
                                case 7: firstLiFontSize = 'xxx-large'; break;
                                default: firstLiFontSize = 'small'; 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    getLastOrderList.style.fontSize = firstLiFontSize;
                }
            }
        }, 0);
    }
}

Actually the above code generate the output as I expected but I need get the output as different manner
So, I need to modify the code to achieve my expected output
I need to

remove the hard-coded switch case statement
remove the setTimeOut Method, without effecting current function
get the output html code without implementing wrapped functionality like below




     test
    


below I attached the screenshot of editor view
screenshot of editor view
The output of the editor view is below
<ol style="font-size: small;">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>s</li>
</ol>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<ol style="font-size: x-small;">
    <li>
        <font size="1">sds</font>
    </li>
    <li>
        <font size="1">f</font>
    </li>
    <li>
        <font size="1">ff</font>
    </li>
</ol>
<p>
    <font size="1">&nbsp;</font>
</p>
<ol style="font-size: medium;">
    <li>
        <font size="3">sdssds</font>
    </li>
    <li>
        <font size="3">d</font>
    </li>
    <li>
        <font size="3">sd</font>
    </li>
</ol>
<p>
    <font size="3">&nbsp;</font>
</p>
<ol style="font-size: x-large;">
    <li>
        <font size="5">sd</font>
    </li>
    <li>
        <font size="5">sd</font>
    </li>
    <li>
        <font size="5">ds</font>
    </li>
</ol>

Let's see the output clearly every <ol> element takes the font size from first li of that <ol> so this output is exactly correct, so same as i need to get the output with the help of Telerik Solution with my above mentioned requirements
so please checkout and let me know if you have idea about this

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I got the answer from Telerik Official Side, so please use this below code to fix the issue
  function OnClientCommandExecuting(editor, args) {
      let commandName = args.get_commandName();

      if (commandName == "RealFontSize" || commandName == "FontSize") {
          let selElem = editor.getSelectedElement(); 

          if (selElem.tagName == "LI" || selElem.tagName == "UL" || selElem.tagName == "OL") {
               selElem.style.fontSize = fontSizeIntoPixels(args.get_value());
          } else selElem.style.fontSize = fontSizeIntoPixels(args.get_value());
          args.set_cancel(true);
      }
  }

  function fontSizeIntoPixels(fsValue) {
      switch (fsValue) {
          case 1:
              return "10px";
              break;
          case 2:
              return "13px";
              break;
          case 3:
              return "16px";
              break;
          case 4:
              return "18px";
              break;
          case 5:
              return "24px";
              break;
          case 6:
              return "32px";
              break;
          case 7:
              return "48px";
              break;
      }
  }

